# how to work CORRECTLY with SSL_read() and select()?

Tags: windows, sockets, openssl, nonblocking

I try to make a C++ TLS client with OpenSSL which use non-blocking socket on Windows.

I want to work with SSL_read()/SSL_write() and select() functions but I don't find the algorithme which work well and the net not provide good and simple exemple. There is allready a timeout return by select() after the last block of data recved.

I don't understand OpenSSL api, SSL_pending() return already 0 and select a time out??

Select cause a criticale delay at last bloc of data.

My algorithme for recv_buffer() is this:

I have function which check if a socket is readable or writeable (work well):

```
int CSocket::socket_RWable(int rw_flag, const int time_out)
{
    fd_set rwfs;
    int error = 0;
    struct timeval timeout;

    try
    {
        memset(&timeout, 0, sizeof(struct timeval));
        timeout.tv_sec = time_out;

        while( 1 ) // boucle de surveillance
        {
            FD_ZERO(&rwfs);
            FD_SET(m_socket, &rwfs);

            // surveiller la socket en lecture ou ecriture
            if(rw_flag == R_MODE)   
                error = select(m_socket+1, &rwfs, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
            else if(rw_flag == W_MODE) 
                error = select(m_socket+1, NULL, &rwfs, NULL, &timeout);

            if(error < 0) // echec de select
                throw 1;
            else if(error == 0) // fin du time out
                throw 2;

            // Une opération d' entree/sortie sur la socket est disponible
            if(FD_ISSET(m_socket, &rwfs) != 0)  
            {
                FD_CLR(m_socket, &rwfs );
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(int ret)
    {
        FD_CLR(m_socket, &rwfs );
        if(ret == 1) throw CErreur("[-] CSocket : select : ", CWinUtil::Win_sys_error(NET_ERROR));
        else if(ret == 2)   return -1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

and this function recve the data into a buffer and cause a time out after the las block of data:

```
int CTLSClient::recv_buffer(char *buffer, const int buffer_size, const int  time_out)
{
    int selectErr = 0;
    int sslErr = 0;
    int retRead = 0;    
    int recvData = 0;   

    selectErr = m_socket->socket_RWable(R_MODE, time_out);

    while(selectErr == 0)
    {
        retRead = SSL_read(m_ssl, buffer+recvData, buffer_size-recvData);

        sslErr = SSL_get_error(m_ssl, retRead);

        if(sslErr == SSL_ERROR_NONE)
        {
            cout<<"DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data="<<retRead<<endl;
            recvData += retRead;
        }
        else if(sslErr == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
        {
            cout<<"DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()"<<endl;
            selectErr = m_socket->socket_RWable(R_MODE, time_out);
        }
        else if(sslErr == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
        {
            cout<<"DEBUG 4  SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE select()"<<endl;
            selectErr = m_socket->socket_RWable(W_MODE, time_out);
        }
        else if(sslErr == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }

    return recvData;
}
```

this is a output with connection to a POP3 server:

```
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=35
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
[S]+OK BLU0-POP617 POP3 server ready
total data -> 35
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=23
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
[S]+OK password required
total data -> 23
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=30
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
[S]+OK mailbox has 180 messages
total data -> 30
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=18
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
[S]+OK 180 12374432
total data -> 18
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=13
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
[S]+OK 1 23899
total data -> 13
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=5
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=8192
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=8192
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
DEBUG 2  SSL_ERROR_NONE recv data=7521
DEBUG 3  SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ select()
[S]total data -> 23910
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already read the headers, for some reason SSL_read() hangs after reading the email message and returns SSL_WANT_READ.  I solved this problem by looping through the message body one line at a time until I find the ending period.  When I reach this line, I call SSL_pending(). Although there is no pending data, it prevents an endless loop where SSL_read() returns SSL_WANT_READ.  However, I am looking for a better solution.

```
for(;;)
{
    char *line = ReadLine(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(line != NULL)
    {
        if(*line == '.')
        {
            int pending = SSL_pending(ssl);
            if(pending > 0)
            {
                int read = SSL_read(ssl,buf,pending);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function reads one character at a time until it reaches an end of line character and returns the line.

```
char *ReadLine(SSL *ssl, char *buf, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *ptr = NULL;
    for (ptr = str; size > 1; size--, ptr++)
    {
        i = SSL_read(out, ptr, 1);
        switch (SSL_get_error(out, i)){
        case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            break;
        default:
            TRACE("SSL problem\r\n");
        }

        if (*ptr == '\n')
            break;   
        if (*ptr == '\r'){
            ptr--;
        }
    }


    *ptr = '\0';

    return(str);
}
```